# How to access workspace files in Jenkins from shared libraries

Tags: git, jenkins, shared-libraries

My jenkins setup is a master on my local environment on Windows.

My Jenkins project uses the groovy pipeline. It uses a git repo that contains a property filed that needs to be processed in a jenkins shared library.

I don't know how to calculate the absolute path of this property file to my shared library.

I tried using the relative path but the shared library is not executed in the same context as the workspace.
The solution needs to work for a master / slaves scenario.

My git project is structured like this

```
/
/properties.json
/assets                           # this folder contains some source code
```

My step in my pipeline looks like this

```
steps {
    bat "ECHO \"Building project\""
    generateJdbcProperties(
        new File('properties.json')
    )
}
```

I get the following path in my shared library : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\properties.json` but I want to get the following path : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ci-tests`. The path consists of the workspace, plus the name of my git repo which is in this case `ci-tests`.

I've tried using the $WORKSPACE env variable but I wasn't able to use it properly in my groovy code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
new File("${WORKSPACE}\\properties.json")
```

Comment: That was it. I was using `' '`. Thanks!